# Replace in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have very large number of unique features in a column in pandas dataframe.
As observed in the picture there so many unique ip's i cannot use pd.replace syntax as it is only applicable for finite replacement of elements .
I want to replace every unique value in a column by a specific number and number of unique are appox 5716,
[image: Dataset View]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) from scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

l = [
    '192.168.1.1',
    '192.168.1.2',
    '192.168.1.3',
    '192.168.1.1'
]

le = LabelEncoder()

transformed = le.fit_transform(l)
inverse_transformed = le.inverse_transform(transformed)

print(transformed, inverse_transformed)
>>> [0 1 2 0] ['192.168.1.1' '192.168.1.2' '192.168.1.3' '192.168.1.1']
```

Comment: Thank u soo much :) . It really helped